# How to analyze unsuccessful builds in the analysis phase?

Tags: bazel

A bazel binary that I am building completes unsuccessfully during the analysis phase. What flags and tools can I use to debug why it fails during analysis.

Currently, clean builds return the following output

```
ERROR: build interrupted
INFO: Elapsed time: 57.819 s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (133 packages loaded)
```

If I retry building after failed completion, I receive the following output

```
ERROR: build interrupted
INFO: Elapsed time: 55.514 s
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (68 packages loaded)
```

What flags can I use to identify

- what packages are being loaded
- what package the build is being interrupted on
- whether the interruption is coming from a timeout or an external process.

Essentially, something similar to --verbose_failures but for the analysis phase rather than the execution phrase.

So far I have ran my build through the build profiler, and have not been able to glean any insight. Here is the output of my build:

```
WARNING: This information is intended for consumption by Blaze developers only, and may change at any time.  Script against it at your own risk
INFO: Loading /<>/result
INFO: bazel profile for <> at Mon Jun 04 00:10:11 GMT 2018, build ID: <>, 49405 record(s)
INFO: Aggregating task statistics

=== PHASE SUMMARY INFORMATION ===

Total launch phase time         9.00 ms    0.02%
Total init phase time           91.0 ms    0.16%
Total loading phase time        1.345 s    2.30%
Total analysis phase time      57.063 s   97.53%
Total run time                 58.508 s  100.00%

=== INIT PHASE INFORMATION ===

Total init phase time                    91.0 ms

Total time (across all threads) spent on:
              Type    Total    Count     Average

=== LOADING PHASE INFORMATION ===

Total loading phase time                 1.345 s

Total time (across all threads) spent on:
              Type    Total    Count     Average
    CREATE_PACKAGE    0.67%        9     3.55 ms
          VFS_STAT    0.69%      605     0.05 ms
           VFS_DIR    0.96%      255     0.18 ms
          VFS_OPEN    2.02%        8     12.1 ms
          VFS_READ    0.00%        5     0.01 ms
          VFS_GLOB   23.74%     1220     0.93 ms
     SKYFRAME_EVAL   24.44%        3      389 ms
       SKYFUNCTION   36.95%     8443     0.21 ms
     SKYLARK_LEXER    0.19%       31     0.29 ms
    SKYLARK_PARSER    0.68%       31     1.04 ms
   SKYLARK_USER_FN    0.03%        5     0.27 ms
SKYLARK_BUILTIN_FN    5.91%      349     0.81 ms

=== ANALYSIS PHASE INFORMATION ===

Total analysis phase time               57.063 s

Total time (across all threads) spent on:
              Type    Total    Count     Average
    CREATE_PACKAGE    0.30%      138     3.96 ms
          VFS_STAT    0.05%     2381     0.03 ms
           VFS_DIR    0.19%     1020     0.35 ms
          VFS_OPEN    0.04%      128     0.61 ms
          VFS_READ    0.00%      128     0.01 ms
          VFS_GLOB    0.92%     3763     0.45 ms
     SKYFRAME_EVAL   31.13%        1    57.037 s
       SKYFUNCTION   65.21%    32328     3.70 ms
     SKYLARK_LEXER    0.01%      147     0.10 ms
    SKYLARK_PARSER    0.03%      147     0.39 ms
   SKYLARK_USER_FN    0.20%      343     1.08 ms
```

As far as my command, I am running

```
bazel build src:MY_TARGET --embed_label MY_LABEL --stamp --show_loading_progress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--host_jvm_debug` startup flag to debug Bazel itself during a build.

From https://bazel.build/contributing.html:

> **Debugging Bazel**
>
> Start creating a debug configuration for both C++ and
>   Java in your `.bazelrc` with the following:
>
> ```
> build:debug -c dbg
> build:debug --javacopt="-g"
> build:debug --copt="-g"
> build:debug --strip="never"
> ```
>
> Then you can rebuild Bazel with `bazel build --config debug //src:bazel` and use your favorite debugger to start debugging.
>
> For debugging the C++ client you can just run it from `gdb` or `lldb` as
>   you normally would. But if you want to debug the Java code, you must
>   attach to the server using the following:
>
> - Run Bazel with debugging option `--host_jvm_debug` before the command    (e.g., `bazel --batch --host_jvm_debug build //src:bazel`).
> - Attach a debugger to the port `5005`. With `jdb` for instance, run `jdb -attach localhost:5005`. From within Eclipse, use the remote
>     Java application launch configuration.
> - Our IntelliJ plugin has built-in debugging support